# Mechanize form submission failing with correct information

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I am attempting to submit a form in Ruby using the gem **Mechanize**, and even when I have confirmed that the field data is being set properly with

```
pp login_form.username
pp login_form.password
```

the form submission fails and returns the output included at the bottom of this post. What factors may be taken into play which cause my submission to fail?

**Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: utf-8

require "mechanize"

# Prepare Mechanize agent
agent = Mechanize.new do |a|
  a.user_agent_alias = 'Mac FireFox'
  a.follow_meta_refresh = true
end

# Retrieve login form
chess_url = "https://www.chess.no"
login_form = agent.get(chess_url).form_with(:dom_id => "mypageform_id")

# Fill login form
login_form.username = 'myuser'
login_form.password = 'mypass'

# Submit login form
my_page = agent.submit(login_form, login_form.buttons.first)

pp my_page
```

**Output** (generated by `pp my_page`)

```
#<Mechanize::File:0x007f9bbd008b28
@body=
"{\"status\":\"error\",\"errorcode\":99,\"message\":\"Invalid username or password\",\"context\":\"userlogin\"}",
@code="200",
@filename="login.html",
@full_path=false,
@response=
  {"date"=>"Tue, 25 Mar 2014 22:09:20 GMT",
   "server"=>"Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)",
   "x-powered-by"=>"PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.7",
   "cache-control"=>"no-cache",
   "x-server-name"=>"c01web06.keyteq.no",
   "keep-alive"=>"timeout=3",
   "connection"=>"Keep-Alive",
   "transfer-encoding"=>"chunked",
   "content-type"=>"application/json"},
@uri=#<URI::HTTPS:0x007f9bbd03bc30 URL:https://www.chess.no/cat/mypage/login>>
```

Comment: Well it says invalid username or password so I would start there. You're not actually submitting myuser/mypass are you?

Comment: Of course not, just replaced my real data. I suspect some Javascript might be intercepting the data in the login process, considering Mechanize does not handle Javascript, this might be a cause of error.

Comment: You'll want to proxy your requests through fiddler or charles and take a look at them in that case.